# "Application has stopped", error in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am a newbie.

I am getting: "Application has stopped", message, after clicking on the Browse (File Explorer) button.

What I have done till now? I tried searching on Internet, exactly implied that in code but still error. Checked on Stack Overflow but didn't work, checked all code, icons location, checked `logcat` error messages.

What this code is doing when clicked on Browse Button? Simply, File exploring in the "/sdcard".
I am not getting why the error is coming?

The app is executing without error. But error comes after clicking on Browse button.
logcat message:

```
06-03 13:32:23.796 28652-28652/com.jby.filecrypto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method getFile(View) in the activity class com.jby.filecrypto.FileexplorerActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'skipButton'
                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3113)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3660)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14427)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getFile [class android.view.View]
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
                                                                    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3106)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3660) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14427) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am attaching the files [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2x72D21rB9dUmlhT1hPekpSUFk&usp=sharing).

Every answer will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message explains the problem rather plainly. Your `Activity` is missing a method you've specified in a layout file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there are two ways to write setOnClickListener:

(1) is to just only put android:onClick="variable_name"; in the .xml file. In this case there is no need to use setOnClickListener() in the .java file.

(2) the other one is to remove the line android:onClick="variable_name"; in the .xml file and use seOnClickListener() in the .java file.

The second one worked well in my case. I don't know why the first one is not working, but as of question, answer is, there can be something thats why the button is not listening well, so can try any other method, like for me the second way worked.

Comment: Also I have changed the getfile name as told by Sush. I tried to upvote him/her but I have no much points to upvote, as only 15 above reputation candidates can upvote, at this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getfile(View view)
```

change to

```
 public void getFile(View view)
```

Comment: I cahanged it to getFile(View view) in Fileexplorer.java but still same error.

Comment: Please check new logcat, editted. Still same, Application has stopped.

Comment: Why -2 I don't know? But is it a crime to ask a question after trying and searching? That is -2 on a well formatted question (I tried for formatting). And I think what usually happens, someone(having good reputation) will put the question close, saying off the topic :). But all are not bad.

Comment: @Bati Could you update the codes you have in Google Drive to reflect these changes?